# getsheetbyname with variable cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet called Audit with cell B1 corresponding to a specific shopID.

I have built a sheet with each shopID called ShopID+PrevAudit (555PrevAudit)

When they complete the audit they click a button that should copy values and format to the corresponding sheet i've created but I'm getting hung up on calling the correct sheet based on a B1 entry.

This is what I had been using but it was static and i want to make this easier on myself.  I'm not sure why this is so difficult for me.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
function copyaudit() {
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
    var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName('Audit');
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

    var tempSheet = source.getSheetByName('555PrevAudit');
    var tempRange = tempSheet.getRange('A1:L51');

    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');

    sourceRange.copyTo(tempRange);  // paste all formats?, broken references
    tempRange.offset(0, 0, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length)
    .setValues(sourceValues);  // paste all values (over broken refs)
}
```

Comment: source sheet is always Audit.  The destination sheet will depend on what is in cell B1.  If it were 555 than the destination sheet would be 555PrevAudit, if it were 321 the destination would be 321PrevAudit.  This example all sheet are in the same spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a JS template string, you can generate the sheet name:

```
`${destID}PrevAudit`
```

To put it in context:

```
function copyaudit() 
{
  const range = 'A1:L51';
  
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Audit');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(range);

  // Get B1
  let destID = sourceRange.getValues()[0][1];
  let destSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(`${destID}PrevAudit`);

  sourceRange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(range));
}
```